# getting StackOverflowError while initializing a static variable

Tags: java, java-8

Below is the Minimal Verifiable Example of a piece of code which i stumbled upon.

```
package test_package;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class TestClass {

  public static final String CONST_STR = " some_data "+ getMoreData(e -> e.getId()==3);

  private static String getMoreData(Predicate<TestEnum> p){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(TestEnum e : TestEnum.values()){
      if(p.test(e)){
        sb.append(e.name());
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(CONST_STR);
  }
}

enum TestEnum{
  OP1(1),OP2(2),OP3(3);

  private final int id;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  TestEnum(int id){
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

when i am trying to compile it its giving me

> Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError

can anyone point me where i am going wrong in it ?

I am getting below error when trying to compile `javac test_package/TestClass.java`

> The system is out of resources. Consult the following stack trace for
>   details. java.lang.StackOverflowError     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope.dupUnshared(Scope.java:144)    at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.lambdaEnv(Attr.java:2639)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2305)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2435)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)...

and my version is `javac 1.8.0_112`

Thanks in Anticipation !

Comment: I tested. No issue for me.

Comment: Could you please show the whole stack trace along with the line where this exception occurs?

Comment: Are you sure you get the StackOverflowError while compiling? Or at rumtime (when executing it)?

Comment: No issue here too. Maybe this is not the [MCVE] for your real program.

Comment: @STaefi: since the compiler is software, there can be a `StackOverFlowError` while compiling too.

Comment: @STaefi, I know that and wanted to let the OP clarify his question.

Comment: Hi, i have updated question. error is coming on compile time

Comment: @QBrute updated, can you plz check now.

Comment: [Reproduces on Ideone](https://ideone.com/p10iol).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[It's bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166672), fixed in javac-9. I tried the latest javac-9 and it would not reproduce.

To get around that you could do:

```
public static final String CONST_STR;

static {
    CONST_STR = " some_data " + getMoreData(e -> e.getId() == 3);
}
```

which seems to compile just fine...