# Final String with variable part

Tags: java, string, jenkins, final

I have a Set with some values. I want to write IN clause of a query using these values. Here is my code -

```
Class A {
      private static final Set<String> values = Stream.of("NY", "NJ").collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

      public static set<String> getValues() { return  values;}
}
```

I want to create the query -
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE STATE IN ('NY', 'NJ');

Following code works -

```
Class B {
     public static final String query = "SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE STATE IN ('NY', 'NJ')";
}
```

Follwing code is one on my local while it is failing on jenkins with the error -
The system is out of resources.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.lambdaEnv(Attr.java:2639)

```
Class B {
     public static final String query = "SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE STATE IN " + A.getValues().stream().map(key->"'" + key + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(",","(",")")) ;
}
```

I'm guessing this doesn't have anything to do with the keyword "final" since it's working on my local. Can someone please help me with what's causing this error on jenkins.

Comment: I am not sure about why the StackOverFlowError happens, but you are doing a lot of weird hacks to get a static SQL query. Seems awfully like using bad practices on top of eachother to get a few static variables in code which probably don't need to be static anyway. But about the exception, maybe this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300252/getting-stackoverflowerror-while-initializing-a-static-variable

Comment: The solution given in the link worked for me. Thanks for that. I can accept it if you can add that as an answer. Also, is there a better way of writing this? I want to have a Set so that if I get more cities in future I can add them to the set and avoid having to make updates at multiple places in the code.